# Displaying Euro sign on PDF using XSLT 1.0

Tags: .net, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, currency-formatting

**Summary:**
**Need to display € sign on pdf**

I'm using the .Net framework (4.0)'s `XslCompiledTransform` class to perform XSLT. The font family used on the XSL is Times New Roman. I'm using [FO.Net](http://fonet.codeplex.com/) as my XSL-FO processor.

I'm trying to display the Euro sign (€)  that is part of my input XML. However, my output pdf displays `&euro;` instead of the € sign.

```
<CurrencySymbol>
€
</CurrencySymbol>
```

Some of the relevant sections of my XSL file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-15"?>
```

I've tried using `&#8364;` and `&#x20AC;` but if I use these, nothing is displayed at all.

eg:  `<xsl:value-of select="'&#x20AC;'"/>`

Thanks for any help and your time! Please let me know if any additional info is needed.

Comment: What FO processor are you using?

Comment: Looks like in ISO-8859-15 euro character is 0xA4 so if this is your output encoding you may want to try putting &#xA4; instead of &#x20AC;

Comment: @Pawel: Using `&#xA4;` won't help. It is a different character. Numerical character references refer to Unicode code points, which are independent of encoding.

Comment: @questionask - you are right. I tried the following and it worked for me:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="iso-8859-15"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Currency>€</Currency>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

It worked if the xslt file itself was encoded as ISO-8859-15, utf-8 and utf-16 (I checked the output with a binary editor). Are you sure that in your xslt the output encoding is set correctly? The encoding in the xml header is for the xslt itself

Comment: and not the file produced by this xslt.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. The problem is hardcoded in the FONET.DLL. In the class `TrueTypeFont` method `MapCharacter` is written as:

```
public override ushort MapCharacter(char c) 
{
    if (c > Byte.MaxValue) 
        return (ushort) FirstChar;
    return mapping.MapCharacter(c);
}
```

So any character with a value greater than 255 will be "ignored". I downloaded the sources (from https://fonet.codeplex.com/) and modified the method to:

```
public override ushort MapCharacter(char c) 
{
    return mapping.MapCharacter(c);
}
```

Using this library with this new method, the euro-symbol magically became visible!

Comment: Absolutely nothing helped except this solution. There was a comment above this code: "TrueType fonts only support the Basic and Extended Latin blocks". So I'm not sure if this could make some other trouble.